# selecting div in an each loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm facing some problems in this piece of code.
My goal is to click a random div and then fill a div inside it with content.

There are four different contents for the first four clicks. First click - content 1; second click - content 2 , and so on.

The problem is that the last filled content fills also every other div and not only the selected one.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xamonix/g0go9sgh/

Here is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var clickCount = 0;
 $('.covers .col-md-4').each(function() {
     $('.front', this).click(function() {
         clickCount = (clickCount == 5) ? 0 : clickCount;
         if (clickCount == 0) {
             $('.back').html("<div class='back_content_1'>CONTENT 1</div>");
             $(this).closest('#flip-toggle').addClass('flip');
         } else if (clickCount == 1) {
             $('.back').html("<div class='back_content_1'>CONTENT 2</div>");
             $(this).closest('#flip-toggle').addClass('flip');

         } else if (clickCount == 2) {
             $('.back').html("<div class='back_content_1'>CONTENT 3</div>");
             $(this).closest('#flip-toggle').addClass('flip');
         } else if (clickCount == 3) {
             $('.back').html("<div class='back_content_1'>CONTENT 4</div>");
             $(this).closest('#flip-toggle').addClass('flip');
         } else if (clickCount == 4) {
             return false;
         }
         clickCount++;
     });
 });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are targetting all elements with class .back, with your selector:

```
  $('.back').html
```

Use :   `$(this).next().html...`, for example.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g0go9sgh/9/